# nginx/1.10.0 (Ubuntu) 502 Bad Gateway in my joomla website

Tags: joomla-3.5

from past two days i'm getting the error in all my joomla 3.5.1 websites nginx/1.10.0 (Ubuntu)
502 Bad Gateway

even though my hosting provider says that he hasn't updated anything and i also have not added or updated anything in my website.

Does anyone has any solution???

the website url is http://pyramidwealth.in

Comment: Updating your question with recent errors in the error log file at /var/log/nginx/ or similar might help.